# Trying to run multiple outbound websocket connections. All running on the same foreign port

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to run a web socket on my home server using python. It works great as long as only one connection is going out from my machine. When I try to run another instance of a client connection from the same computer, it will lock up until the first one disconnects. However, it can handle two connections at once, as long as they aren't coming out of the same machine. (I.e. I had one client running on my computer, and another running locally on the server and they both sent and received data). I did some digging and found out that while the outgoing local port for the client is always different, the outgoing foreign port is always glued to 3000, the port of the websocket I'm trying to connect to. Why is the outbound port always stuck at 3000? Why can't it be the same as the local port? Here is my server code:

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


# identifies the port
PORT = "3000"

# identifies the hostname
HOST = "rx-78-2"

# sets the trust message that essentially acts as a secondary handshake
TURTLE_MESSAGE = "Shake my hand bro"

# sets the message that will indicate a disconnection 
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "END-OF-LINE"

turtles = []

# handles a new connection
async def handle_connect(websocket, path):
    print(f"CONNECTION RECIEVED @ {path}")
    turtleIndex = len(turtles)
    turtles.append(f"Turtle {len(turtles)}")

    print(turtles[turtleIndex])


    connected = True

    first_msg = await websocket.recv()
    if first_msg != TURTLE_MESSAGE:
        print("Connection Refused")
        await websocket.send("return print('Connection Refused')")
        await websocket.close()
    else:
        print("Connection Established")
        await websocket.send("return print('Connection Established')")

    while connected:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            break
        print(msg)
        await websocket.send("return turtle.turnRight()")

    print("CLOSING SOCKET")

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handle_connect, HOST, PORT, ssl=None, compression=None):
        await asyncio.Future()

print("STARTING SERVER")
asyncio.run(main())
```

(don't mind the goofy stuff in there)

The client code here is irrelevant because it needs to be fixed either on my system as a whole, or on the server side, due to the actual application of the clients will be very limited.

**So to sum up**

- I need to have multiple websocket clients running on my machine, connecting to my home server
- They all keep trying to take the foreign outbound 3000 port, causing only one client to be able to run at any given time
- It cannot be fixed in the client code, it either needs to be with my machine or the server code because the application of the actual clients doesn't provide enough control for me to be able to fix the issue there.

My machine is running Fedora 39 w/ KDE Plasma, and the server is running a RHEL based OS. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I used netstat to see the outbound and incoming connections for both the clients and the server. The server reports a connection to it's port 3000, which is to be expected, from the connecting machine's port 3000. Looking at the outgoing connection from the client, the local port is completely different (typically somewhere in the range of 50000), but the foreign port is always 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid... whoops.

It turns out for the reason to the binding (and only one connection) was because I was trying to push multiple connections through the external IP of the server, not the local one (on LAN) for reasons that I'll get to in a moment. I only had the one port open on the external router, so the first connection took that one up, and the rest couldn't get through.

The clients that I'm trying to run don't let you connect to a local server, so I had to connect to the outside port. I found a workaround for this, though, and was able to get it up and running just fine.

I'm not exactly sure why that is though, becuase I know that multiple clients on a minecraft server can connect on one port, so I don't see why this is any different. Oh well. Connecting locally is good enough for what I'm doing so I don't need the help anymore.

Edit:
The odd behavior I was experiencing stemmed from a circular routing issue, nothing wrong with anything I was doing. It was a pain but I got everything sorted out.